# Getting ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I am finding "ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows" error in my procedure and I searched for its solution and got an idea that to fix this kind of issue, we have to use cursor or collections in our procedure.

And I use cursor in my procedure and the logis/technique is little bit different from normal procedure. So, I m confused how to change my logic in the procedure so that I can use collections,records or bulk collects ?

Thanks and here is my procedure.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE DB_TZ_PROC AUTHID CURRENT_USER IS 

V_DBNAME VARCHAR2(20);
V_INSTANCE VARCHAR2(10);
V_TIME VARCHAR2(20);
V_DB_TIME TIMESTAMP(6);
V_SERVER_TZ VARCHAR2(10);
V_RPT_SER_TIME VARCHAR2(50);
V_SERVER_DATE DATE;
V_SESSION_TZ VARCHAR2(30);
V_DBZONE VARCHAR2(10);
V_DATE DATE;
V_ERRORSTRING varchar2(4000);
V_EXEC_STRING VARCHAR2(6000);
TABLE_NAME VARCHAR2(30):='TIMEZONE_DIFF';
INN_EXCEPTION VARCHAR2(30):='INNER_EXCEPTION';
OUT_EXCEPTION VARCHAR2(30):='OUTER_EXCEPTION';


CURSOR DBNAME_CUR IS SELECT DBNAME FROM CRMODDEV.FHM_DB_D WHERE (podname ='xyz');

BEGIN

 OPEN DBNAME_CUR;
LOOP
 FETCH DBNAME_CUR INTO V_DBNAME;
 EXIT WHEN DBNAME_CUR%NOTFOUND;
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('V_DBNAME1 :'||V_DBNAME);

  BEGIN


 V_EXEC_STRING:='select instance_name,
   startup_time,
   database_default_time,
   server_tz,
   rpt_server_time,
   session_tz, 
   dbtime_zone,
   server_current_date,
   timezone_date
from (select a.inst_id,
    upper(b.instance_name) instance_name,
    to_char(b.startup_time, ''YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'') startup_time,
    SYSTIMESTAMP database_default_time,
    substr(to_char(SYSTIMESTAMP), 30) server_tz,
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP rpt_server_time,
    substr(to_char(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 30) session_tz, 
    dbtimezone dbtime_zone,
    to_date(to_char(max(sample_time),''YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS''),''YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'') server_current_date,
    SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE ''UTC'' timezone_date 
      from gv$active_session_history@'||V_DBNAME||' a, gv$instance@'||V_DBNAME||' b
    where a.inst_id = b.inst_id
    group by a.inst_id,
    upper(b.instance_name),
    to_char(b.startup_time, ''YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI''),
    dbtimezone)


    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('V_DBNAME2 :'||V_DBNAME); 

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE  V_EXEC_STRING INTO V_INSTANCE,V_TIME,V_DB_TIME,V_SERVER_TZ,V_RPT_SER_TIME,V_SESSION_TZ,V_DBZONE,V_SERVER_DATE,V_DATE; 


    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('V_INSTANCE:'||V_INSTANCE);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('V_SERVER_TZ:'||V_SERVER_TZ);
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('V_DBZONE:'||V_DBZONE);

  INSERT INTO TIMEZONE_DIFF(DB_INSTANCE,STARTUP_TIME,DATABASE_DEFAULT_TIME,SERVER_TZ,RPT_SERVER_TIME,SESSION_TZ,DBZONE,TIMEZONE_DATE,COLLECTION_DATE) 
VALUES  (V_INSTANCE,V_TIME,V_DB_TIME,V_SERVER_TZ,V_RPT_SER_TIME,V_SESSION_TZ,V_DBZONE,V_DATE,TRUNC(SYSDATE));        

  COMMIT;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('V_DBNAME3 :'||V_DBNAME);

  UPDATE TIMEZONE_DIFF SET COLLECTION_DATE=TRUNC(COLLECTION_DATE);               

   COMMIT;

 -- INNER EXCEPTION         
   EXCEPTION

                     WHEN OTHERS THEN                            
       V_ERRORSTRING:= 'INSERT INTO CRMODDEV.TIMEZONE_DIFF_LOG VALUES ('''||V_DBNAME||''','''||TABLE_NAME||''','''||SQLCODE||''','''||SQLERRM||''',SYSDATE,'''||INN_EXCEPTION||''')';
                    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_errorstring;
                                          COMMIT;
                   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE FOR INNER BLOCK:'||DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE);


  END;

 END LOOP;

CLOSE DBNAME_CUR;

 -- OUTER EXCEPTION

 EXCEPTION
           WHEN OTHERS THEN 
V_ERRORSTRING:= 'INSERT INTO CRMODDEV.TIMEZONE_DIFF_LOG VALUES ('''||V_DBNAME||''','''||TABLE_NAME||''','''||SQLCODE||''','''||SQLERRM||''',SYSDATE,'''||OUT_EXCEPTION||''')';
                    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_errorstring;
                    COMMIT;
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE FOR OUTER BLOCK:'||DBMS_UTILITY.FORMAT_ERROR_BACKTRACE);


END DB_TZ_PROC;
```

Answer (score 0):

The immediate problem appears to be that the `select` statement you are building in `V_EXEC_STRING` returns multiple rows.  But then you are trying to fetch the output into a set of scalar variables in your `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.  It would be possible to declare all your variables as collections and do a `BULK COLLECT` into those collections.  But since all you are doing is turning around and inserting your results into the `timezone_diff` table, you really ought to be building an `INSERT ... SELECT` statement so that you don't have to bother fetching any data into local variables.

```
 V_EXEC_STRING:='INSERT INTO TIMEZONE_DIFF(DB_INSTANCE,STARTUP_TIME,DATABASE_DEFAULT_TIME,' ||             
                '                          SERVER_TZ,RPT_SERVER_TIME,SESSION_TZ,DBZONE,' ||
                '                          TIMEZONE_DATE,COLLECTION_DATE) ' ||
                ' select instance_name, ' ||
                ...

  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_exec_string;
```

It is not obvious to me why you are bothering with dynamic SQL for your inserts into `CRMODDEV.TIMEZONE_DIFF_LOG` or why you are committing inside a loop in a non-restartable process.  Neither of those things would cause the particular error you're getting but both are likely to bite you at some point.

Comment: Thanks @Justin . So, I have to make 3 changes here ?
#1. Declare a collection and put all the variables into it. 
#2. Using Bulk Collect, I need to push the data into those variables in side the collections. #3. As suggested, I ll use the Execute immediate v_exec_string; ?

Comment: @user3181672 - Most likely, you want to eliminate the local variables and just build the `INSERT ... SELECT` statement that I suggested.  If you really want to separate the `SELECT` from the `INSERT` for some reason, you could declare collections and bulk collect into those collections.  But it generally doesn't make sense to fetch data into local variables if you can do everything in a single SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks @ Justin. I want to use Nested Table. So I created types - TIMEZONE_DIFF_type and TIMEZONE_DIFF_type_details and the table TIMEZONE_DIFF_1 where insertion will happen finally.
How can I insert the data into the table using Nested table in a procedure? All codes are available here.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22930684/inserting-data-into-table-using-nested-table